# KendoUI ComboBox displaying incorrect parsing of REST JSON

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, combobox, kendo-ui

I have a restful service responding with `{"SearchMode":["Customer","Address","Street","City"]}`, everything looks fine. I'm trying to add each of these as an option in a Kendo ComboBox. However, it's parsing it out and showing each letter as an option:

- {
- "
- S
- e
- a
- r
- c
- h

you get the point. Here is what I'm doing in the javascript to get this. I'm learning Kendo controls so any help is appreciated.

```
$(#cboSearch").kendoComboBox({autobind:false, minLength:3, datasource:{type:json, serverFiltering: true, transport:{ read: { url: "http://myrestservicehere?f="}}} });
```

I know I'm missing something obvious and looking forward for some guidance, thanks.
Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing in the `DataSource` definition saying where in the returned object is the array containing the options. This is done using `schema.data`. It should be:

```
$("#cboSearch").kendoComboBox({
    autoBind       : false,
    minLength      : 3,
    dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        serverFiltering: true,
        transport      : {
            read: {
                url: "http://myrestservicehere?f="
            }
        },
        schema         : {
            data: "SearchMode"
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks OnaBai. See above, I was missing the read of the datasource. I can post the solution if you wish, and thanks for the note. I restructured it and it worked. The earlier version failed when I included the schema. Thanks for giving me another solution.

Answer (score 1):

The ComboBox doesn't support binding to array of strings. You could try changing your JSON to something like:

```
{
  "SearchMode": [
     {"text":"Customer"},
     {"text":"Address"},
     {"text":"Street"},
     {"text":"City"}
  ]
}
```

Then configure the combobox like this:

```
$("#cboSearch").kendoComboBox({
    autoBind       : false,
    minLength      : 3,
    dataTextField  : "text",
    dataValueField : "text",
    dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        serverFiltering: true,
        transport      : {
            read: {
                url: "http://myrestservicehere?f="
            }
        },
        schema         : {
            data: "SearchMode"
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks Atanas, I've figured it out by adding a datasource variable then a datasource.read(); This was necessary as the schema properties were causing it to not display anything.